# TypeError: a.split is not a function at r (angular.js:26393)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typeerror

I understand what the error means but I don't split anything in my app. This error appears to come from the angular.js file itself and wasn't there some days ago. I wonder if anyone has the same issue and if this is a bug.

Error:

> TypeError: a.split is not a function
>       at r (angular.js:26393)

Comment: are you importing `angular.js` or `angular.min.js`? have you minified _your_ code?

Comment: You will need to look at the stack trace. The last function of _your own_ code is probably the culprit. Or if it's all Angular code, I would guess you are passing `null` or `undefined` or some other non-string type where a string is expected.

Comment: there is no .split() function in my code, thats why I was wondering

Comment: Im importing angular.js

Comment: can you show a full error? where does it occur (how it appeared)? what other libraries are you using?

Comment: TypeError: a.split is not a function
    at r (angular.js:26393)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18210)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18480)
    at angular.js:1952
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5040)
    at c (angular.js:1950)
    at Uc (angular.js:1970)
    at xe (angular.js:1855)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:33826)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.3.js:3232)

Comment: Full error doesnt give me more details, theres something that tries to be .split() but it gives error because it is expected to be a string, and its driving me crazy cause theres nothing at all in my code that i am .split() ing.. the libraries i import are angular.js and jquery.js. I was just wondering if this could be a bug in angular itself

Comment: Could you post a link to your exact version? https://code.angularjs.org/ has them all if you start there.

Comment: `a` `r` `m` is an indication of some minified code. If you are importing AngularJS as `angular.js` then it's some other library. You usually don't use jQuery since AngularJS has jQLite, they contradict each other. Is there any reason for you to use jQuery?

Comment: it would better if you provide the code that throws an error

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same error.

Check if you are using a boolean variable as a `className`.
It solved my problem.

Also check, exactly in which function this error is occurring.